Ansible Azure Dynamic plugin getting errors
I am trying to use Ansible.
I have used Terraform to deploy systems in Azure and now trying to use Ansible to configure Domain Controller and WorkStation. While I am try to dynamically create inventory from Azure, but getting the following error. Any help or guidance would be very useful
  (venv)  ansible-inventory -i  inventory_azure_rm.yml  --graph -vv
ansible-inventory [core 2.12.10]
  config file = ./ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['./ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = ./ansible/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = ./ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = ./ansible/venv/bin/ansible-inventory
  python version = 3.10.15 (main, Sep  7 2024, 18:35:38) [GCC 13.2.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.4
  libyaml = True
Using ./ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse ./ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml with yaml plugin: Plugin
configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]: Unable to parse ./ansible/inventory_azure_rm.yml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

Added Inventory file details
plugin: azure_rm
auth_source: cli
include_vm_resource_groups:
- xxx-lab
conditional_groups:
  domain_controllers: "tags.kind == 'domain-controller'"
  workstations: "tags.kind == 'workstation'"
keyed_groups:
- prefix: tag
  key: tags


Without the content of the inventory, there is not much we can really tell you.

I have added the inventory file, that is dynamically trying to create the inventory. This is modified from the following GitHub project. https://github.com/christophetd/Adaz
